# Powershell - Run external powershell script and capture output - Can't pass parameters

Tags: powershell, ampersand

I have a problem running a powershell script from within another powershell script, passing parameters and capturing the output. I have tried using the ampersand operator, calling it via `powershell.exe -Command` but nothing seems to work.

What seems to work is using fixed parameter and values stored in a variable like this `C:\path\to\script.ps1 -arg1 $value`.
This may present a solution if nothing else works, but I would like to run the command similar to this `& $pathToScript $params 2>&1` (the `2>&1`is for capturing error output as well as standard).

---

Sometimes the construct prints just the path to the script, 
sometimes it says `Cannot run file in the middle of pipeline` and 
sometimes it complains about it cannot find the mentioned script file (I sometimes have spaces in my path, but I thought quoting it would suffice: quoting was done like this `` $path = "`"C:\path\with space\to\script.ps1`"" ``).

This is the simplified function I want to use this in:

```
Function captureScriptOutput
{
    #the function receives the script path and parameters
    param($path, $params)
    
    #this works if no params are passed, but I need params!
    $output = & $path $params 2>&1 | Out-String
}
```

Comment: How crazy does everything go?

Comment: Edited my question now, thanks for indicating.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem with the help of a colleague.

We went a little indirection and included a `cd` into the respective directory and ran the command afterwards. This works like a charm.

Solution source code:

```
Function captureScriptOutput
{
    param($fileName, $params)

    cd "C:\into\path with\space"
    $output = & .\$fileName $params 2>&1 | Out-String
}
```

This works and even captures the error output, I hope some other folks encountering this kind of problem can use this to fix their problems.

Cheerioh and thanks for reply!

Answer (score 0):

Try with invoke-expression but you need test how many quote needed

```
Invoke-expression "$path $param"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried a bit around and am encountering problems with the quotation. I tried this: ``Invoke-Expression -Command "`"$path`" $param"``, that only echoed back the path, same as I tried to quote the string `$path` is holding: ``$path = "`"C:\path.ps1`""``. This [MSDN Page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730965.aspx) suggests enclosing the path variable in single quotes, which did not work around the issue with spaces in the path. Well, any further suggestions?

Comment: Someone else on google suggested using the ampersand together with Invoke-Expression like this: `Invoke-Expression -Command "& $path"`. This leads to the Powershell complaining it does not recognise the command `&`.